# Using Automapper MapFrom to get Count() with WHERE filtering

Tags: automapper

Given this entity:

```
public class Album
{
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Artist { get; set; }
public virtual AlbumCollections AlbumCollections { get; set; }
}
```

Along with this DTO

```
public class AlbumDto
{
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Artist { get; set; }
public int AlbumCount { get; set; }
}
```

How can I return a count of albums where the name and artist match (i.e., a count of duplicate albums)?

My first attempt:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Album, AlbumDto>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.AlbumCount, opt => opt.MapFrom(so => so.AlbumCollections.Album.Where(x => x.Name == x.Name && x.Artist == x.Artist).Count()) );
```

... returns the result:

```
{
name: "My Album",
artist: "My Artist",
albumCount: "3"
},
{
name: "My Album",
artist: "My Artist",
albumCount: "3"
},
{
name: "My Different Album",
artist: "My Different Artist",
albumCount: "3"
}
```

The count should be "2" on the first two items, and "1" on the last item. How do I properly set up the WHERE filter?

Comment: You should probably use a custom resolver to calculate the count. See an example here -> https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers

Comment: It was my WHERE clause ... should have been Where(x => x.Name == so.Name && x.Artist == so.Artist).Count())